# How to give title to a table created using renderReactable

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

When I execute following code in R, it works well.

```
example<- reactable(data.frame(country=c("argentina","brazil"),
                               value=c(1,2)
))
withtitle <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(example, 
                                         h2(class = "title", "Top CRAN Packages of 2019"))
print(withtitle)
```

However, when I execute the same code with shiny using

```
reactableOutput("table_1")
```

and

```
output$table_1 <- renderReactable({

example<- reactable(data.frame(country=c("argentina","brazil"),
                               value=c(1,2)
))
withtitle <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(example, 
                                         h2(class = "title", "Top CRAN Packages of 2019"))

print(withtitle)

})
```

It gives error:

> Warning in renderWidget(instance) :   Ignoring prepended content;
> prependContent can't be used in a Shiny render call

Kindly guide me to give title to the above table and other parameters like background color, font color etc. for the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks YBS.  I got the idea from your answer.  I used div() text in ui before reactableOutput() and could get the heading with choice color and background.  The code used is given below:

```
            div("Top CRAN Packages of 2019", style = "text-align: center; 
                  background-color: #3380FF; color:yellow; font-size:200%"),
            reactableOutput("table_1")
```

Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

You can just define the title in the `ui` section.  Perhaps you are looking for this

```
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Top CRAN Packages of 2019"),
  reactableOutput("table_1")
)
 
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table_1 <- renderReactable({
    
    example<- reactable(data.frame(country=c("argentina","brazil"),value=c(1,2)))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please note that your code gives me the same error but I do get correct output in the viewer pane in RStudio.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Yes, I also get correct output in viewer pane but not when I run with my main code.  However, defining title in ui goes well.  Can you please suggest how to change color and background color of the title after defining in ui?